# Matrix Multiplication using 1D arrays in C, formula and order?

Tags: arrays, c, matrix, row, matrix-multiplication

I have this code to multiply two matrices stored in 1D arrays.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void matrix_multiplier(int n, int m, int k,
            double* C, double* arr_1, double* arr_2) {
  
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int p = 0; p < m; p++)
                sum = sum + A[p + i * k ] * B[j + p * n];
            C[j + i * n] = sum;
        }
    }
}



int main(){

  int n = 3;
  int m = 3;
  int k = 2;
    
  double arr_1[10] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0};

  double arr_2[10] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0};

  double *C = calloc(n*k, sizeof(double));


  matrix_multiplier(n, m, k, C, arr_1, arr_2);


  printf("\n");
  printf("input matrices\n");

   for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
        for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
             printf("%f ", arr_1[j * m+ i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }


  printf("\n");


  for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
        for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
             printf("%f ", arr_2[j * m+ i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }


   printf("output matrix\n");

   for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
        for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
             printf("%f ", C[j * m+ i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }


     free(C);

    return 0;
}
```

However I'm not sure `sum = sum + A[p + i * k ] * B[j + p * n];` line is entirely correct. I tried following some pseudocode and it led me only to this. Furthermore, I'm not quite sure if this code is storing the data in row-major or column-major order, cause i do actually need it to be in row-major.

Comment: It's odd that your matrices store `double` values yet you use `int sum = 0;` in the matrix multiplication code.  Your sample data _is_ all integers, but …

Comment: Mistake on my part, it should actually take doubles i just forgot to actually make the test data doubles instead of ints, it is fixed now!

Comment: I'd write the code using VLAs first — somewhat like this: `void matrix_multiply(int m, int p, int n, float matrix1[m][p], float matrix2[p][n], float output[m][n]) { matrix_zero(m, n, output); for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) for (int j = 0; j < p; j++) for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) output[i][k] += matrix1[i][j] * matrix2[j][k]; }`. Then I'd translate the subscript notations. This doesn't use your intermediate `sum` variable, so it needs to zero the output matrix; using `sum` means you don't need to zero the output matrix. Just make sure it is the correct type (`float` in my code; `double` in yours).

Comment: I apologize — although the code posted before is correct, it works with an arcane sequence of loops. This code is simpler to understand and does use a `sum` variable: `void matrix_multiply(int m, int p, int n, double matrix1[m][p], double matrix2[p][n], double output[m][n]) { for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) { for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) { double sum = 0.0; for (int k = 0; k < p; k++) sum += matrix1[i][k] * matrix2[k][j]; output[i][j] = sum; } } }`. It uses `double` instead of `float` throughout, and the roles of `j` and `k` have been changed.  It better simulates hand matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

Using integer for accumulation of doubles is a bad idea:
Replace:

```
int sum = 0;
```

with

```
double sum = 0;
```

---

Another issue is indexing the `C` array.
It should be:

```
C[j + i * k] = ...
```

For every increment of `i` by 1, the `j` is incremented `k` times.

Comment: Something is still wrong, if i set k lower than m its wrong data output